Inherit from "FluentUI Blazor DataGrid"
How can a component inherit from "FluentUI Blazor DataGrid"? I get the following error when I try to inherit from "FluentUI Blazor DataGrid", anyone have experience with this?
Error:

CS0411
The type arguments for method 'TypeInference.CreatePropertyColumn_7<TGridItem, TProp>(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int, Expression<Func<TGridItem, TProp>>, int, bool?, int, Align)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

InheritGrid.razor:
@typeparam TItem
@inherits FluentDataGrid<TItem>

@{
      base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

InheritGrid.razor.cs:
namespace TishtarUI.Test
{
    public partial class InheritGrid<TItem> : FluentDataGrid<TItem>
    {
    }
}

Home.razor:
<InheritGrid Items="@Persons" TGridItem="Person">
   <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.FirstName)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
</InheritGrid>


There is a work-around, <PropertyColumn TGridItem="Person" TProp="string" Property="@(p => p.FirstName)" ... /> but that's not very pretty.

Fixed! Thank you!
